# Why scrapy spider does not go to parse method

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a webpage with python scrapy library.

I have code as follows:

```
class AutoscoutDetailsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vehicle details"
    reference_url = ''
    reference = '' 

    def __init__(self, reference_url, reference, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AutoscoutDetailsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.reference_url = reference_url
        self.reference = reference
        destination_url = "https://www.autoscout24.be/nl/aanbod/volkswagen-polo-1-2i-12v-base-birthday-climatronic-benzine-zilver-8913b173-cad5-ec63-e053-e250040a09a8"
        self.start_urls = [destination_url]
        add_logs(self.start_urls)

    def handle_error_response(self):
        add_logs("NOT EXISTS. REFERENCE {} AND REFERENCE URL {}.".format(self.reference, self.reference_url))

    def handle_gone_response(self):
        add_logs("SOLD or NOT AVAILABLE Reference {} and reference_url {} is sold or not available.".format(self.reference, self.reference_url))

    def parse(self, response):
        add_logs("THIS IS RESPONSE {}".format(response))

        if response.status == 404:
            self.handle_error_response()

        if response.status == 410:
            self.handle_gone_response()

        if response.status == 200:
            pass

def start_get_vehicle_job(reference_url, reference):
    try:
        def f(q):
            try:
                runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
                deferred = runner.crawl(AutoscoutDetailsSpider, reference_url, reference)
                deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
                reactor.run()
                q.put(None)
            except Exception as e:
                capture_error(str(e))
                q.put(e)

        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        result = q.get()
        p.join()

        if result is not None:
            raise result

        return {"Success.": "The crawler ({0}) is successfully executed.".format(reference_url)}
    except Exception as e:
        capture_error(str(e))
        return {"Failure": "The crawler ({0}) is NOT successfully executed.".format(reference_url)}


def main(params):
    start_get_vehicle_job(params.get('reference_url', None), params.get('reference', None))
```

Thus, first what is executed is `main`, with main I call `start_get_vehicle_job` with `reference_url` and `reference` as parameters. And then `start_get_vehicle_job` calls scrapy spider `AutoscoutDetailsSpider`.

In `__init__` I add url which need to be scraped. The params `reference` and `reference_url` in `__init__` are correct. `add_logs` function just adds some text to database. And `add_logs` in my case in `__init__` adds the correct url.
[image]

The I should go to `parse` method and there I want to check for the response status. I've added `add_logs("THIS IS RESPONSE {}".format(response))` at the top of the `parse` method but I do not see that message in my logs table.

When I test this url with `scrapy shell` it works fine and I get `response.status 404`, what correct is.

[image]

It's like the scrapy spider doesn't come to parse method at all.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else have the same problem, the solution was to add `handle_httpstatus_list = [404]` in the top of the spider:

```
class AutoscoutDetailsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404] ############# This line was the key
    name = "vehicle details"
    reference_url = ''
    reference = ''
```

Per default it handles only 200 statuses ([docs](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.httperror)). To handle other statuses you need to add them to `handle_httpstatus_list`